# how do I parse the local json file from file manager flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have seen lot of examples from parsing the `json` file from the `assets`

But How do I get the get the json file from file manager and parse it?

```
void openJsonFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
      if (file.path.contains('.json')) {
        parse(file);
      }
    } else {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
  }

  void parse(File file) async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString(file.path);
    List<JsonItem> items = (jsonDecode(response) as List<dynamic>)
        .map((e) => JsonItem.fromJson(e))
        .toList();
    Navigator.of(dkey.currentState!.context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => JsonParsedListScreen(items: items)),
    );
  }


class JsonItem {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  JsonItem({this.id, this.name});

  factory JsonItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return JsonItem(name: json['name'], id: json['id']);
  }
}


E/flutter (20466): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.example.play/cache/file_picker/sample.json
E/flutter (20466): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
E/flutter (20466): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20466): #1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:72:27)
E/flutter (20466): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20466): #2      HomePage.parse (package:play/nextPage.dart:52:29)
E/flutter (20466): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20466):
```

I get this log
for this line       **final String response = await rootBundle.loadString(file.path);**

Comment: The question title is misleading, you don't have a problem (at least currently) with parsing the json file, you're unable to load it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for loading from `assets`,

```
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString(file.path);
```

but reading from a file is something like this:

```
final response = await file.readAsString();
```